# How can I crop an image form a google web search in Android

Tags: android, crop, web-search

I build a Google web search like example below.

```
String url = "https://www.google.com"
Uri picUri = Uri.parse(url);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

best solution so far was [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Using-built-in-CropImageActivity)

Then I want do crop founded Images and save the Image (png) on my device.
Unfortunately I just found solutions that recognized images locally on the device and not on a Webpage.

So can anyone help me?

Comment: then download the image and use cropping tool on this image

Comment: That's a Workaround I just think about, but I would prefer to use any cropping tool in my `webView`